# Swizzle Shell Command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that scripts does something like

```
Command1
```

Command1 is a closed source binary that within it, it executes something like.

```
xcodebuild <some args>
<some magic>
xcodebuild <some different args>
<some magic again>
```

What I want to do is to have a custom script like:

```
./xcodebuild-cleanup-script
```

That executes **immediately** after xcodebuild command. But since I don't have the source of the Command1 binary, I can't do it.

Is there a way for me to override `xcodebuild` command to make it call my custom command something like

new `xcodebuild` should be:

- call original `xcodebuild`
- call `./xcodebuild-cleanup-script`

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean, is there a way that you could rename xcodebuild and put your own executable where it was, so that it could wrap the original xcodebuild with some additional functionality?

Comment: I don't really want to do that. Because that would affect the entire system. I would like something to be local to my script. I'm reading about preexec. Is there something that could be triggerd after (postexec maybe)?

Comment: If the proprietary code doesn't set its own path, and makes use of the path it's given, you could give it a custom PATH environment variable that listed your executable with the same name first. Your executable could then either explicitly set its own PATH, refer to the executable by a full pathname, or remove the directory it's in from the path it was given. If the executable is subject to that kind of hackery, I could convert this comment to an answer. But it's not really a good answer, so I'd only want to do that if it solved your issue and nobody else had a better way.

Comment: Unfortunately, it references xcodebuild with absolute path.

Comment: @EdGrimm actually your solution might be correct. Can you provide details on how to pass custom path to the script and revert to the original path again?

Comment: If you are allowed to modify Command1, simplest solution would seem to be to create a tweaked copy by doing a binary edit that replaces the original absolute path with one to your own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customary way to achieve this is to put your own wrapper somewhere in front of your `PATH`.  This assumes that `Command1` doesn't have a hard-coded internal `PATH`.

Assuming your `PATH` look something like

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

and `xcodebuild` is in `/usr/local/bin`, you can create your own wrapper in `$HOME/bin/xcodebuild` and augment your `PATH` to have `$HOME/bin` in front.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/bin
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then within `$HOME/bin/xcodebuild` you can hard-code the path, or possibly install a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/xcodebuild $HOME/bin/xcodebuild.real
```

and use `xcodebuild.real` to refer to this command from within your script.

```
#!/bin/sh
xcodebuild.real "$@"
rc=$?
xcodebuild-cleanup-script
exit $rc
```

Perhaps you can even move the functionality of `xcodebuild-cleanup-script` to this script altogether.

If you have admin privileges, you might do the same within `/usr/local/bin`:  move `xcodebuild` to `xcodebuild.real` and create a wrapper which calls this, perhaps conditionally:

```
#!/bin/sh
xcodebuild.real "$@"
rc=$?
if [ "$run_xcodebuild_wrapper" ]; then
    xcodebuild-cleanup-script
fi
exit $rc
```

Now you will only run `xcodebuild-cleanup-script` when the environment variable `run_xcodebuild_wrapper` is set to a non-empty string, and otherwise run `xcodebuild.real` transparently.  This will work even if `Command1` hard-codes the path to `xcodebuild`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I added
export PATH=$(pwd)/scripts/xcode:$PATH
Then inside the scripts/xcode I placed a script named xccodebuild with content

/usr/bin/xcodebuild $@
xcodebuild-cleanup-script

Comment: You neel double quotes around `$@`

Answer (score 0):

Since the path to xcodebuild is hardcoded and you are probably not allowed to change the behaviour of xcodebuild to always do the cleanup - since other tools might want to use it without cleanup -, I can think of one really, really dirty trick:

Rename `xcodebuild` in the same way as triplee suggested (for instance to xcodebuild.real) and place a shell script `xcodebuild` at the expected location with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cleanup_script=./xcodebuild-cleanup-script
xcodebuild.real
[[ ${DO_XCODEBUILD_CLEANUP:-N} == Y ]] && [[ -x $cleanup_script ]] && $cleanup_script
```

Now if you run

```
 DO_XCODEBUILD_CLEANUP=Y Command1
```

it would do the cleanup.

Comment: This only seems to offer the dubious change of preferring uppercase for the variable name compared to the last section in my answer, and some pretty strange syntax in the first comparison (do you really mean for the variable to contain `>`?)

Comment: @tripleee : Oops, I didn't see that you also had a solution checking a variable. Did you add this variant it later? Or maybe I was just blind.... And thank you for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 0):

@tripleee's solution is the correct one. I just wanted to share how I did it.
In my script I added

```
export PATH=$(pwd)/scripts/xcode:$PATH

Command1
```

Then inside `scripts/xcode` directory, I created a script named `xcodebuild` which contains

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild $@

# custom command
./xcodebuild-cleanup-script
```